# Why are some columns truncated in my table output?

Tags: tables

I have a latex table generated, it has 12 columns, but it is displaying only 11 columns...why is it so? Is there any mistake I am doing? Should I work something with the font size because I have another table with 12 columns but its displaying only 8 cols..it has more cell contents than this...

```
\documentclass{article}\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\hline
1 & 186.30 & 101.52 & 128.33 & 148.02 & 132.08 & 138.63 & 107.98 & 133.09 & 134.12 & 119.23 & 133.21 & 165.73 \\ 
2 & 104.03 & 184.67 & 184.07 & 169.27 & 117.85 & 107.67 & 169.89 & 111.93 & 185.41 &  134.30 & 198.12 & 120.83 \\ 
3 & 170.20 & 189.47 & 142.98 & 106.06 & 116.85 & 120.74 & 100.51 & 195.18 & 196.31 & 189.16 & 180.00 & 191.78 \\ 
4 & 176.23 & 187.77 & 127.99 & 194.66 & 135.87 & 152.42 & 137.35 & 109.88 & 162.07 & 171.81 & 136.07 & 122.29 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The table is larger than the `textwidth` and so the rest is printed in the margin.

Comment: It just doesn't fit on the page. Either shrink the font, rotate the table, or rearrange the data some other way so it fits.

Comment: lscape from the graphics bundle or the pdflscape package could be useful for rotating, too (both @ CTAN).

Answer (score 1):

As frabjous said in his comment, you may *"[e]ither shrink the font, rotate the table, or rearrange the data some other way so it fits"*. Shrinking the font seems to be out of the question for your example table, as even a switch to `\tiny` is not sufficient to fit it into the page margins. For rotating, use the [rotating](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package and its `sidewaystable` environment. (And use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` -- [here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/510) why.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{r}}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\hline
1 & 186.30 & 101.52 & 128.33 & 148.02 & 132.08 & 138.63 & 107.98 & 133.09 & 134.12 & 119.23 & 133.21 & 165.73 \\ 
2 & 104.03 & 184.67 & 184.07 & 169.27 & 117.85 & 107.67 & 169.89 & 111.93 & 185.41 &  134.30 & 198.12 & 120.83 \\ 
3 & 170.20 & 189.47 & 142.98 & 106.06 & 116.85 & 120.74 & 100.51 & 195.18 & 196.31 & 189.16 & 180.00 & 191.78 \\ 
4 & 176.23 & 187.77 & 127.99 & 194.66 & 135.87 & 152.42 & 137.35 & 109.88 & 162.07 & 171.81 & 136.07 & 122.29 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep...can we assign these functions from R.. as I got this code from R..thank u...

Comment: @alex: Sorry, I'm not familiar with R.

Comment: I've written functions in MATLAB to write out LaTeX versions of tables with whatever formatting I wanted, so you can probably do something similar in R. However, a 4x13 table may not be the best idea to begin with. Maybe you can make it 13 rows by 4 columns instead, or find another way of grouping the data so that it's less wide.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more suggestions to make the `tabular` fit within your margins:

---

You could resize the entire table using the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) command `\resizebox{<h-len>}{<v-len>}{<stuff>}` in the following way:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{*{13}{r}}
  ...
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

The `<h-len>=\linewidth` will stretch/shrink the entire table to width `\linewidth`, while `<v-len>=!` keeps the aspect ratio in tact.

---

Modify the inter-column spacing either **manually** via

```
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{@{\hspace{<len>}}r@{\hspace{<len>}}}}% Inter-column spacing of <len>
```

or via setting lengths like `\tabcolsep` or `\extracolsep`. See the [fixed-width table entry on the TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fixwidtab) for more details.

There are plenty more, of course. But all depend on your preference and eventual document use.